# Is there any way to combine useContext with an arrow function?

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-hooks, use-context

I'd like to use the `useContext` and `createContext` with an arrow function. I want to be able to use variables inside `Foo` and pass them in `createContext`.

```
export const Foo = () => {
...
}
```

Combine above and below.

```
export const Bar = React.createContext({ lang: 'en'})
```

Answer (score 1):

Given `React` documentation, it doesn't seem there is a way we can do this easily, one trick is to use a function self called :

```js
React.createContext((() => {
   // any code here returning an object
   return {}
   // the function is self-called here
})())
```

but I would not recommend this way as it is not easily understandable and not so clean. However, it's the only way i can think about.